# using ffmpeg to replace a single frame based on timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to CLI ffmpeg to replace a specific frame at a specified interval with another image? I know how to extract *all* frames from a video, and re-stitch as another video, but I am looking to avoid this process, if possible.

My goal:

- Given a video file input.mp4
- Given a PNG file, image.png and given its known to occur at exactly a specific timestamp within input.mp4
- create out.mp4 with image.png replacing that position of input.mp4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic command is

```
ffmpeg -i video -i image \
       -filter_complex \
         "[1]setpts=4.40/TB[im];[0][im]overlay=eof_action=pass" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

where `4.40` is the timestamp of the frame to be replaced.

Comment: Is it possible to use this to replace multiple frames with multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

Note that images default to a [framerate of 25fps](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/13074).  Thus, for timestamps that are not multiples of (1/25=)0.04s, the framerate must be specified (eg, to replace frame at timestamp 3.5035 in a 29.97fps video):

```
ffmpeg -i input.vid -itsoffset 3.5035 -framerate 30000/1001 -i frame.png -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1]overlay=eof_action=pass" output.vid
```

This technique works just as well for replacing multiple sequential frames (eg, to replace frames starting at 107s in a 12.5fps video):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -itsoffset 107 -framerate 25/2 -i '107+%06d.png' -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1]overlay=eof_action=pass" output.mp4
```

This only works for videos with constant framerates (CFR).  For VFR video, I have a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63880205/1670156).